# How to catch scrolling event in DBGrid in Delphi

Tags: delphi, events, scrollbar, dbgrid

I have a DBGrid, I need to run some code, each time the horizontal scrollbar is used. I couldn't find such event in DBGrid. Can you advise something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will help. It shows an example for trapping the scrolling events of a regular TStringGrid. [Synchronize the Scrolling of two TStringgrids?](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1603)

Comment: This works, but I have a lack of knowledge in one point here, could you assist? I created a new component TScrDBGrid, but I have a DBGrid already placed on a form with lots of properties and events already declared, so I'd hate to delete and create a new one. Is there a way I can "migrate" this DBGrid to the new class?

Comment: You can install your new component into a package, and install that package into the IDE so the compiler is aware of it. Close the unit with the DBGrid you want to replace, so it's not open in the IDE. *MAKE A COPY OF THE .DFM AND PAS FILES FIRST!* Open the text .DFM in Notepad and replace the TDBGrid with your new grid's classname. Do the same with the matching .PAS file's interface section, and make sure you add your new unit's name to the *interface* uses clause. Save the file, and then reopen it in the IDE. If you did things right, all should be fine. If not, restore the backup copies.

Comment: One last question. While this event works now, the scrollbar stopped working, it seems that while catching this event, it stops it from proceding further to windows for actual scrolling operation. How should I solve this?

Comment: @Tofig: did call inherited in your WMHScroll procedure? If not you would have to provide the expected behavior yourself

Comment: Are you calling the OldGridProc?

Comment: Yes, after I added inherited all became OK. Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: @Tofig: There is a hack you can use for not redeclaring all your components. If you create a descendent component with the exact name that you are descending from but references the parent component including the unit name, you should with just adding that unit be able to continue without changing components. So you would declare a TDBGrid = class(DBGrids.TDBGrid) with your added functionality in a new unit like 'MyGrid.pas', by adding that to those areas where you DBGrid is used, you should be ok. I am trying to find the article where I picked this up from.

Answer (score 7):

There is a WMHScroll procedure in TCustomGrid, but it is private. You can't use it in a DBGrid.
You would have to create your own TDBGrid descendant and do your own

```
procedure WMHScroll(var Msg: TWMHScroll); message WM_HSCROLL;
```

or do some seriously bad hacking...

**Update**: trick/hack to sneak your code in...

```
[...]
    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, DB, ADODB, Grids, DBGrids;

    type
      // Hack to redeclare your TDBGrid here whitout the the form designer going mad
      TDBGrid = class(DBGrids.TDBGrid)
        procedure WMHScroll(var Msg: TWMHScroll); message WM_HSCROLL;
      end;

      TForm8 = class(TForm)
        DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
        DataSource1: TDataSource;
        ADODataSet1: TADODataSet;
        ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form8: TForm8;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    { TDBGrid }

    procedure TDBGrid.WMHScroll(var Msg: TWMHScroll);
    begin
      case Msg.ScrollCode of
        SB_ENDSCROLL: OutputDebugString('SB_ENDSCROLL') ;
        SB_LEFT:OutputDebugString('SB_LEFT');
        SB_RIGHT:OutputDebugString('SB_RIGHT');
        SB_LINELEFT:OutputDebugString('SB_LINELEFT');
        SB_LINERIGHT:OutputDebugString('SB_LINERIGHT');
        SB_PAGELEFT:OutputDebugString('SB_PAGELEFT');
        SB_PAGERIGHT:OutputDebugString('SB_PAGERIGHT');
        SB_THUMBPOSITION:OutputDebugString('SB_THUMBPOSITION');
      end;
      inherited; // to keep the expected behavior
    end;
[...]
```

**Update2**: Note that you can move your special TDBGrid code to a separate unit (recommended), just be sure to put this **unit name AFTER DBGrids in your Form's uses clause**.

Comment: Yep, that is what yozey's article actually suggests. I have already created such component. Now the problem is - how to migrate from old one to the new one, without deleting and creating again?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that such hacking was possible :)

Comment: Tofig, See my Update2. You can avoid changing your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check this at the moment, but if I recall correctly the event's there, but not published.  Try creating a control that descends from TDBGrid and publishes the scroll bar event.

Comment: I checked this, and still couldn't find such event. There is an element called ScrollBars, but no event related to it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Wrong answer, obviously. It catches the *vertical* scrollbar, but not the *horizontal* one.

You don't catch it at the DBGrid level. You catch it at the BeforeScroll or AfterScroll of the attached TDataSet. It fires with either the scrollbar, up and down arrow keys, page up 
and page down keys, etc. that occurs  within the DBGrid.

Comment: It works for vertical scrolling, but not horizontal. How do you make it fire for horizontal scrolling?

Comment: I don't think it would do much good to the OP. He wants to trap the Horizontal scrolling, i.e when the visible colummns change.

Comment: Ah, of course you're right. I missed the "horizontal". Thanks for the correction. @Tofig: I don't think you can catch the horizontal scroll; at least a quick test app I wrote couldn't. Left and right arrow keys work in the OnColEnter and OnColExit events, but aren't triggered via the scrollbar as the selected column isn't changed.

Comment: yozey's answer can actually help, but I have a problem with that (see comment to his answer), maybe you could help?

Comment: @Tofig: See my comment to yozey's answer.

Comment: After scroll of TDataSet, is fired outside grid scroll event, so this solution does not answer the question